# Databse instuctions want me to use linux specific functions but I am on windows and don't know how to get around this

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, windows, operating-system

[Here is the github page](https://github.com/mdeff/fma) with the database and usage guide that I have tried to follow so far.

I will begin explining my thought process so bear with me while I get to how exactly the title relates to the project.

So on the initial page you can see the tutorial for using this data and right off the bat you see curl functions, cat, and make. Instead of using curl I simply downloaded the data I want, and attempted to use the  python notebook that they want you to use to get started with using the data (you can find this in the "usage" file on the git page). So I attempted to run this code after importing the libraries listed....

```
 %matplotlib inline

import os

import IPython.display as ipd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import sklearn as skl
import sklearn.utils, sklearn.preprocessing, sklearn.decomposition, sklearn.svm
import librosa
import librosa.display

import utils

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (17, 5)

# Directory where mp3 are stored.
AUDIO_DIR = os.environ.get('AUDIO_DIR')

# Load metadata and features.
tracks = utils.load('tracks.csv')
genres = utils.load('genres.csv')
features = utils.load('features.csv')
echonest = utils.load('echonest.csv')

np.testing.assert_array_equal(features.index, tracks.index)
assert echonest.index.isin(tracks.index).all()

tracks.shape, genres.shape, features.shape, echonest.shape
```

....and while the imports certainly seem to load correctly, I run into the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

After doing some searching, this error seems to be because the "utils.load" function is simply returning "none". The files that it is supposed to be loading are hundreds of megabytes large, so the only reason this could be happening are if the load function isn't working properly.

I figure that this could be because the makefile hasn't been run, and the configurations are unchanged. Is there a way for me to go through the same processes described on this git using windows? Or is there another solution to this issue?

I am really quite lost here so all help is appreciated. thanks

edit: 
here is the full error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9bb62f40a8b8> in <module>
     10 print(tracks)
     11 
---> 12 np.testing.assert_array_equal(features.index, tracks.index)
     13 assert echonest.index.isin(tracks.index).all()
     14 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: It looks like this should work in Windows. Could you expand on what is exactly triggering the Exception? It looks like you're inspecting an empty dataset. I suspect the downloaded files are in the wrong directory.

Comment: @torresmateo where do you see it as empty? It's a huge dataset. And the files are in the right directory, I know that because I previously tried it from a different directory and the exception was quite clear as to why it was failing so I got it all into the same folder and now I'm getting this. What do you mean by triggering the exception? It's when I try running the above code

Comment: What I meant is that it's not clear to me which of the lines above results in the error you mentioned, could you expand? or post the stack trace?

Comment: @torresmateo I edited the post and added the full error. sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @torresmateo also something you may want to take a look at is the util.load() function that was custom made. I am worried that it could be malfunctioning due to being outdated or something of the sort

Comment: could you post the result of running `type(features)` and `type(tracks)`? It looks to me that one of those is `None`, and it would help to diagnose what is going on with the code.

Comment: @torresmateo they both return NoneType. I went ahead and tried the same thing with genres and echonest, and they actually return pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. I double checked, and both tracks.csv and features.csv are in the same folder as the others, and not to repeat myself but they are most definitely not empty.

Comment: For the `features` variable, it looks quite clear [what is going on](https://github.com/mdeff/fma/blob/master/utils.py#L183). It's simply a `read_csv` call. Could you try and do that separately instead? and then see if the dataset is properly loaded into the DataFrame?

Comment: you nailed it, thank you so much. doing load csv directly is the workaround here, but I think I figured out why the function wasnt working in the first place. for whatever reason, doing fma_metadata\tracks.csv was returning an error saying that the file does not exist. moving all of the csv files into the parent directory makes everything seem to work just fine, but it's not really a "fix" because now the question is, why wasn't it finding the directory?

Comment: yup so apparently this was all just because python failed to navigate one directory over. not sure what's going on here. even when I use the os library to navigate directly there, it returns nonetype